# Nginx. Возврат локального файла по определенному url

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Имеется файл на сервере

```
/opt/data/data.json
```

Нужно, чтобы при обращению по пути `/?format=json` или по-любому заранее заданному отдавал этот локальный файл.

Понимаю, что можно положить его в статик-директорию и обращаться, этот вариант не подходит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение

PS. Да, вот нашлось решение для `/json`

```
location /json {
   index /opt/data/data.json;
}
```

А вот как задать для пути с параметрами `/?format=json`

Answer (score 1):

Для урла с параметрами `/json-path/?format=json` конфиг такой

```
location /json-path/ {
    index data.$arg_format;
    alias /opt/data/;
}
```

Comment: Красиво. я вот не профессионал в Nginx, но я понял и вопрос, и ответ :-)